# Analytic model for Preventative Maintenance to increase availability?

Tags: reliability

I would like to create a model that can increase Availability via preventative maintenance.  My current model decreases the availability when I include preventative maintenance.  Can you suggest a way to enhance the model so that certain cases of preventative maintenance increase the availability in relation to the no preventative maintenance case?

Consider the formula of Acheived availability ($A_i$):
$$A_i = \frac{MTBM}{MTBM + \bar M}$$

With

$$MTBM = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{MTBM_{cm}} + \frac{1}{MTBM_{pm}}}$$

$$ \bar M = \frac{\lambda * \bar M_{CM} + f * \bar M_{PM}}{\lambda + f} $$

$$ \bar M_{PM} =\frac{\sum_j f_j * M_j}{\sum_j f_j} $$

Now for a toy example...

$MTBM_{CM} = MTBF = 12345 $ hours

$\lambda = \frac{1}{MTBM_{CM}} = \frac{1}{12345} = 8.1 *10^{-5}$

$\bar M_{CM} = MTTR = 8$ hours

$MTBM_{PM} = 720 $ hours (Once a month)

$ f = \frac{1}{MTBM_{PM}} = \frac{1}{720} = 1.389 * 10^{-3}$

$\bar M_{PM} = 1 $ hour

Look at the case for no preventative maintenance:

$MTBM = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{MTBM_{cm}} + 0 } = MTBM_{CM} = 12345 $

e.g. set $MTBM_{PM}$ to infinity since it never happens

$\bar M = \frac{8.1 * 10^{-5} * 8 + 0}{8.1 * 10^{-5} + 0} = 8$

$A_i = \frac{12345}{12345 + 8} = 99.935$ %

Now, if I include preventative maintenance, the availability goes down.

$MTBM = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{12345} + \frac{1}{720}} = 680.32 $ hours

$\bar M = \frac{8.1 *10^{-5} * 8 + 1.389 * 10^{-3} * 1}{8.1 *10^{-5} + 1.389 * 10^{-3}} = 1.39 $ hours

$A_i = \frac{680.32}{680.32 + 1.39} = 99.79$ %

Any ideas on how to show preventative maintenance to be worthwhile?  For example, a method to increase MTBF based on preventative maintenance?